# Don't understand a Python List Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, printing

So, I don't completely understand `.index()` and have been messing around with a  block of code to try and understand it, but it's still not clicking with me.

When messing with this list:

```
myList = [5024,3,True,6.5,12,1,2,2,2]
print(myList)
print(myList.index(2))
```

It comes out printing: `6` 
Where is this 6 coming from?

As another example:

```
myList = [5024,3,True,6.5,12,1,2,2,2]
print(myList)
print(myList.index(4))
```

This is troubleshooted as: `4 is not in list`

but when printing:

```
myList = [5024,3,True,6.5,12,1,2,2,2]
print(myList)
print(myList.index(1))
```

prints: `2`

This is what I don't understand. Is the program counting how many occurrences of 1 there are in this list? If that's the case, when trying to `.index(2)` in this list, it comes printing out `6` instead of `5`.

Whats going on here?

Comment: `myList.index(2)` is 6 because `myList[6]` is 2. `myList.index(1)` is 2 because `myList[2] == 1`.

Answer (score 4):

`True` is being interpreted as 1.

As `myList.index(value)` returns the first index of the `value` so you are getting the values:

```
>>> myList = [5024,3,True,6.5,12,1,2,2,2]
>>> myList.index(2)
6
>>> myList.index(1)
2
```

If you want to find the value at a particular index, use:

```
myList[index]
```

Comment: Ohhh, it clicked! W00t! I never knew a True value was interpreted as an integer. Thanks heemayl!!

Comment: @Jeremy No problem..consider accepting the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer if that helped you so that this issue can be marked as solved.. :)

Comment: `isinstance(True, bool)` and `isinstance(True, int)` will give you `True`. `bool` is derived from `int`.

Answer (score 1):

[Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) - read this article if you need more info.

> `list.index(x)`
>
> > Return the index in the list of the first item whose
> >     value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

You can access elements in your list by index. Indexes start from `0`.
Assuming you have a list, let's see indexes of the elements:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` list_of_nums

`[0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 ]` indexes

So if you use `list_of_nums.index(3)` it will return an index of the first occurrence of the element with value `3` in the list and it's `2`.

In your case `myList.index(2)` returns an index of the first occurrence of the element with value `2` which is `6`.

`myList.index(4)` returns `'4 is not in list'` because there is no such an element with value `4` in your list.
`myList.index(1)` returns an element with value `True` because it's the first occurrence of the element with value `1`, `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

So you can find index of any element in your list if you know its value. 
Also you can use indexes to get value like this:
`myList[1]` - `3`

I hope now it's more clear.

Comment: `List.index('3')` will raise an exception.

Comment: @MarceloCantos sure, but i don't see it in my explanation

Comment: Sorry, comment amended.

Comment: it was just an example, meaning op substitutes List with the name of his list, but i made the adjustments so everyone is happy :)

Comment: It'll still raise an exception.

Comment: Glad to be of service. 